# Highcharts - Columns Showing Negative When Data is Zero

Tags: typescript, highcharts

The only problem I have with this chart and others like it, is when all the data is zero, the bars go below zero. If there are any other columns with data above zero, they show as they should, slightly above zero so you can still hover over them. I cannot place this in a `jsFiddle` because I need external classes to make this work. Hope some of the code is enough. I would assume its with some of the settings I am missing, but I can't seem to find what that setting is.

```js
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
...
import { HighchartUtilities } from .....;

let myData =
    [
        {
            "fullName": "ONE",
            "targetGpPercent": 0E-15,
            "budgetGpPercent": 0.0000
        },
        {
            "fullName": "TWO",
            "targetGpPercent": 0E-15,
            "budgetGpPercent": 0.0000,
        },
        {
            "fullName": "THREE",
            "targetGpPercent": 0E-15,
            "budgetGpPercent": 0.0000,
        }
    ]
;

let element1 = document.createElement('h3');
element1.textContent = '';
let div1 = document.getElementById('container');

try {
    let myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                colorByPoint: false,
                minPointLength: 10
            },
            series: {
                events: {
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            //leave blank to make title disappear
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            //this black magic allows to have one xaxis label per column
            tickPositioner: function () {
                let ticks = this.series[0].processedXData.slice();
                ticks.info = this.tickPositions.info;
                return ticks;
              },
            categories: HighchartUtilities.getValuesInArray(myData, 'fullName'),
            labels: {
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'GP to Budget Percent'
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this) * 100 + '%';
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {tooltip goes here}
            },
            useHTML: true
        },
        legend: {

        },
        navigation: {
            buttonOptions: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },
        series: [
            <Highcharts.SeriesColumnOptions>{
                id: 'prsColumn',
                name: 'Sales Person',
                data: HighchartUtilities.getChangedYDataArray(myData, 
                  'budgetGpPercent'),
                type: 'column'
            },
            <Highcharts.SeriesLineOptions>{
                id: 'teamTargetLine',
                name: 'Targets',
                data: HighchartUtilities.getChangedYDataArray(myData,
                 'targetGpPercent'),
                type: 'line',
                color: 'orange',
                marker: {
                    fillColor: 'orange',
                    symbol: 'square',
                    radius: 3
                }
            }
        ]
    });

} catch (error) {
    element1.textContent = 'ERROR: ' + error.stack;
    document.body.insertBefore(element1, div1);
}
```

Here is what it looks like after the chart renders. 
[image: data]

After you change any of the data values to anything slightly larger than zero, the problem fixes itself. Shown here, one of the values is `0.0001`. The rest are zero.
[image: data2]

Comment: I think 0 shouldn't show anything but since you use `minPointLength` I think you need it. Unfortunately I think that a bug cause this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/otg78jLv/) show the same result.

Comment: @Core972 thanks for putting that in a fiddle. I think I will have to open an issue on their GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is regression, based on the replies [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10646) on the `Highcharts` issues page. The last time this worked was for `v5`, so if you have an older version, using `plotOptions.column.minPointLength` should fix it.

#### EDIT

This is now fixed for milestone `Highcharts v7.1.2`. All versions from `v5` to `v7.1.1` will be broken.